# Samba deny host not blocking that host

Tags: samba

I want to block access to some Samba shares from a certain machine, but somehow I can't get it to work: the machine can still access the shares, and I did restart and reload the samba daemon.

Here is a part of my configuration:

```
    security = share
    hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.0/24
    interfaces = 127.0.0.1 eth1 192.168.1.2
    bind interfaces only = yes
    hosts deny = 192.168.1.251
    encrypt passwords = yes
    guest ok = yes
```

The shares themselves look like this:

```
[examples]
    comment = Example
    path = /foo/bar
    read only = No
    guest ok = yes
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried `192.168.1.` instead of `192.168.1.0/24` ? Also which version of Samba are you using ? Does your config apply to `[global]` ?

Comment: tried that now, does not seem to make a difference. Version is  3.5.10-114.fc12 and yes it is in the [global] section

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, at least a working solution:

I removed the hosts deny line, and changed that hosts allow as follows:

```
    hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 192.168.1. EXCEPT 192.168.1.251
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction: For the machines you want to block access to set the "browseable= no". This field may vary depending on the version of Samba your using

Comment: can you please explain? How do I set browseable=no for specific machines?

Comment: sorry for the delay. at the very bottom of the /etc/smb.conf file
you should add the browseable=no option. For example

[host ] \\ My example of a machine 

 path = /home/host
 writable = yes

 valid users = 
       <<browsable = no >>> add this field for each machine listed in  you config file that you want to block 
 admin users = 

 public = yes
 guest ok = yes
 force user = nobody
 create mask = 777
 directory mask = 777